# Apply css to dropdown

Tags: jquery

I am trying to apply css to dropdown whose values are select.  I am trying this example. But this code not applying the background.  http://jsfiddle.net/Bzbkn/1/

Comment: _What_ style are you trying to apply to _which_ element! We can't read your mind!

Comment: There are no styles defined in the jsfiddle workspace.

Comment: @Jam, I am trying to apply to all the drodown elements using this one $(this).css('background-color', '#FFFF99');

Comment: @Jam,@BNL fiddle link updated..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your inner loop is selecting the list items, but you need to apply the background color to the select box.

Replace

```
$(this).css('background-color', '#FFFF99');
```

With

```
$(this).parent().css('background-color', '#FFFF99');
```

Answer (score 0):

Try SelectBox plugin http://abeautifulsite.net/blog/2011/01/jquery-selectbox-plugin/